# How to handle memo fields in Progress database?

Tags: database-design, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm designing a table in a Progress database, which should contain a memo field. I've created a character field for this, containing up to 500 characters: `x(500)`.
However, when I try to add the corresponding DB field control to a window, I get error 4132, mentioning that only 320 characters are allowed.

What can I do in order to add an editor control to a window in order to show the content of that field?

Comment: To the person who has downvoted this question: this is a technical question I encountered which I described as good as possible, so why the downvote???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character fields are by default shown as fill-in fields, having a maximum size of 320. In order to allow more, the "VIEW-AS" dialog box must be filled in in the data dictionary, hereby a working example:

```
VIEW-AS EDITOR NO-WORD-WRAP MAX-CHARS 500 SCROLLBAR-HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL
     SIZE 35 BY 6
```

When this is done, automatically the AppBuilder will put an editor on the window for showing this DB field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "LARGE" Option on the Editor Widget for more space. An for a really "large" field in the database, you can look for CLOB instead of Character. However CLOB is not supported in any indexes. For the limit of CHARACTER fields, please have a look at:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P122087

A DB record is limited to 32k for all fields.